# On the factorial and singular locus of $\mathbb C[[x,y,z,w]]/(x^2-yz)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Consider the $3$-dimensional Noetherian local ring $R=\mathbb C[[x,y,z,w]]/(x^2-yz)$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=(x,y,z,w)$ .

Then, is it true that $R_P$ is a UFD for every prime ideal $P\ne \mathfrak m$ and $R_Q$ is not regular for some height $2$ prime ideal $Q$ of $R$ ?

I can show that $R$ is normal, hence $R_P$ is regular for every height $1$ prime ideal $P$ of $R$. But I don't know what happens for localization at height $2$ prime ideals.

Please help.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{C}[[x,y,z,w]] $ or it is a misprint and it is $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w] $: sorry to ask this, but this seems more an algebro-geometric related question and so one would expect polynomials to be involved rather than series

Comment: Have you tried $P=(x,y,z)$ and see whether $R_P$ is a UFD?

Comment: @Mohan: I know that $\mathbb C[[x,y,z]]/(x^2-yz)$ is not a UFD ... not sure what happens if my ring is localized at $(x,y,z)$ ...

Comment: @Tommaso Scognamiglio: well I really want a local ring ... hence the power series and not polynomial ...

Comment: Same proof applies .